# Change condition of replaced member function operator bool()

Tags: c++

I have this struct called Status which have this member function bool():

```
struct Status {
public:
    Status();
    operator bool() const;
private:
    bool ok_; //!< true if successful and false otherwise 
    ErrorMessage message_; //!< Message with "Ok" or error
};

Status::Status():
ok_(true),
message_("Ok") {
}
    
Status::operator bool() const {
    return ok_;
}
```

So I replaced operator bool() with function isOk():

```
bool Status::isOk() const {
    return ok_;
}
```

Now, I have some code which used this bool() construction before:

```
if (!(status = CheckLength(currentIndexFrom, currentIndex, currentLexemStartLineNum))) {
    return status;
}
```

CheckLength returns status object:

```
Status CheckLength(Uint32 indexFrom, Uint32 indexTo, Uint32 lineNum) {
    Status status;
    if (indexTo - indexFrom + 1 > limits::xml::tokenValueLength) {
        Char8 message[limits::xml::errorMesLength] = {};
        snprintf(message, sizeof(message),
        "Unexpected expression in string %u, or is larger than %u characters",
        lineNum,
        limits::xml::tokenValueLength);
        status.setError(message);
    }
    return status;
}
```

How to change if (condition) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it like this:

```
if (!(status = CheckLength(currentIndexFrom, currentIndex, currentLexemStartLineNum)).isOk())
```

but why would you do this? AFAIK the operator makes the code more readable so I would keep it as it is, and only use `isOK` where it makes sense.